# AWS Elastic Beanstalk PHP logs not in CloudWatch

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-cloudwatch

I have a PHP application running via AWS Elastic Beanstalk. But the PHP error logs don't seem to be included in CloudWatch alongside the access logs, etc. How do I send them to CloudWatch?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Based on some spelunking, the php error logs seem to be sent to `/var/logs/php-fpm/www-error.log`, decided by the setting in `/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf`:

```
php_admin_value[error_log] = /var/log/php-fpm/www-error.log
```

The only logs sent to CloudWatch for PHP based on the info [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/AWSHowTo.cloudwatchlogs.html) are:

```
/var/log/eb-engine.log
/var/log/eb-hooks.log
/var/log/httpd/access_log
/var/log/httpd/error_log
/var/log/nginx/access.log
/var/log/nginx/error.log
```

You could add custom configuration to have the CloudWatch agent pick up the correct file. Or, you could just add the php error messages to a file already being sent. This can be done via the following in a file `.ebextensions/my.config`:

```
/etc/php-fpm.d/www-my-overrides.conf:
  mode: "000644"
  owner: root
  group: root
  # For some reason, EB configures the php errors to go to /var/log/php-fpm/www-error.log,
  # but doesn't include that file in the default log files sent to CloudWatch. This directs
  # the log files to the error file that is being sent to CloudWatch
  content: |
    [www]
    php_admin_value[error_log] = /var/log/httpd/error_log
```

I'm not sure but I *think* the `www-my-overrides.conf` file name needs to be alphabetically after `www.confg` in the same directory.

Comment: Seems maybe AWS changed something, because I can't get this to work.

Comment: This worked instead: https://serverfault.com/questions/1093921/access-php-error-log-in-aws-elastic-beanstalk

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `nginx`, then you need to use `/var/log/nginx/error.log` as the error log target -- CloudWatch seems to ignore `/var/log/httpd` unless you use Apache, so even if you write to it, the changes won't show up in CloudWatch.

```
files:
  /etc/php-fpm.d/www-my-overrides.conf:
    mode: "000644"
    owner: root
    group: root
    # For some reason, EB configures the php errors to go to /var/log/php-fpm/www-error.log,
    # but doesn't include that file in the default log files sent to CloudWatch. This directs
    # the log files to the error file that is being sent to CloudWatch
    content: |
      [www]
      php_admin_value[error_log] = /var/log/nginx/error.log
```

Additionally, you need to make that file writeable by the php-fpm process which is run as `webapp` by default, plus you want to make sure it exists ... which it won't yet on new instance creation, so it's very important to do both commands:

```
container_commands:
  01-command:
    command: echo "-- DEPLOYMENT --" >> /var/log/nginx/error.log
  02-command:
    command: chmod 666 /var/log/nginx/error.log
```